# IDE does not recognize that function signature in sub-class matches base method

Tags: python, inheritance, intellij-idea

I have a base class with a function that is overridden in subclasses. 
The signature of the function is also (partially) changed, in a way that (to the best of my understanding) complies with the parent class (for example, additional argument is added). 
However, my IDE (IntelliJ IDEA) shows a warning that the signature of the method in the subclass does not match that of the base method.

For example:

```
class BaseFoo():
    def func(self, uid: int, *args, **kwargs):
        pass

class Foo(BaseFoo):
    def func(self, uid: int, name: str, *args, **kwargs):
        pass
```

Shows this warning:

> Signature of method 'Foo.func()' does not  match signature of base method in class 'BaseFoo'

How do I write these classes in a way that will allow the IDE to recognize that the function signature in the subclass does indeed match that of the parent class?

That is, assuming they match in my example (am I wrong?), not wanting to suppress this kind of warning (what if I would've missed the `uid` arg?).

Comment: If the signature is different it's not overriding, it's overloading.

Comment: The signature really is different since you added the `name` argument. If you want the signature to stay the same, use `name` as a keywork argument contained in `kwargs['name']`

Comment: overloading? But it's in a subclass, not in the same class

Comment: @OferSadan not finding another solution, I'm posting your comment as an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not finding any better solution, I'll post Ofer Sadan's comment as an explicit 
answer:
Adding another argument in the subclass's definition of the function will indeed make the signature not match. One can get around it by using *args and **kwargs and taking the new argument from **kwargs.

For example:

```
class BaseFoo:
    def func(self, uid: int, *args, **kwargs):
        pass


class Foo(BaseFoo):
    def func(self, uid: int, *args, **kwargs):
        name: str = kwargs.get('name')
        pass
```

Will not show a warning.
(It will also not show a warning in a usage of `Foo().func(...)` where `name` is mistakenly not supplied... 
This is why this is a partial solution for the question. I'll gladly accept a full solution).